# Doubt in Lemma 2.1.1 in Kesvan Topics in Functional Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, proof-explanation, sobolev-spaces

I was reading Kesvan for functional analysis In that to give an alternative definition of $H^m(\mathbb R^n)$ author uses the following Lemma
[image]

I tried but I do not understand how the Author uses induction argument to prove that.

Please Help me

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Write out the cases $m=1$ and $m=2$ by hand to see whats going on.

Comment: It might help if you dispense with the squares and just look at it as showing $$(1 + x_1 + z_1 + \ldots x_n)^m = \sum_{|\alpha| \le m} B_\alpha x^\alpha$$ for some coeffiicients $B_\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks a lot .I got know